# Android music visualizer

Tags: android, music

I'm looking for an Android app to [visualize music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_visualization) on the device in real-time.

Must-have features:

- It can process the audio from an external app (basically whatever is played on the device). Embedded audio player is not necessary.
- Multiple visualization effects to choose from; not just frequency distribution or waveform, but also more complex patterns (e.g. morphing tunnels, etc.).
- A standalone app is sufficient (no need to display the visualization as a live wallpaper).

Paid apps are OK.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [Music Visualizer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.h6ah4i.android.music_visualizer2), it allows to:

- 11 types of renderings, also randomized: Cover art / Waveform / Shiny Particles / Noise Flow / Colorful Orb / Simple Bars / Heart Beats / Laser / Digital Equalizer / Hex Tiles / Energy Sphere
- Snoop mode (to get input from another media player) with external player app control.

Plus:

- Live wallpaper mode
- Can be used as standalone media player
- Free